# run project in netbeans does nothing at all

Tags: java, netbeans

So I'm trying to run a project of mine in netbeans after changing laptops and importing all files, however, when I try to run one of my projects, nothing happens at all. It happens when I press the green arrow, as well as when I right click the project -> run. I have selected the right file it should run. On my other laptop it runs just fine.

things I've tried:

- restarting netbeans
- closing project and reopening
- remove build.xml and restart netbeans
- clean and build
- locate project.properties, make a non change, save and restart netbeans.

Comment: This is very hard to inspect without any details. What should be happening when you run your application? Is there any error in any output console?

Comment: the application should start printing things in the console when it starts. and with nothing happens when i run, i mean literally nothing, as if you never pressed the run button @f1sh

Comment: is there any output in the "Output" window?

Comment: Did you check if everything is ok in Properties -> Run?

Comment: No, it is as if you've never pressed run @Maia

Comment: Yes, the run configuration is correct

Comment: Did you try to get a dummy project running? A simple form which is just opening? Is the output window opened at all (while compiling e.g.)?

Comment: @Maia yes, i tried running another project, worked fine

Comment: I have recently had the same problem. It broke after I added a testing directory. I can't run or debug my project. The buttons are visible but nothing happens. No print out, no output of any kind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have experienced the exact same thing, very frustrating when nothing at all happens. If Netbeans at least could write something about it in the log file it would be great...

In my case I solved it by updating the `work.dir` in `nbproject/private/private.propteries` since it was not correct any more after a move of the project.

Comment: Very helpful. I found this file, deleted the work.dir and it started working!

Answer (score 0):

For me Netbeans was working fine for months. One day i got a message that i use JDK for windows 32, and since then i couldn't run any program, also the ones which run without flaws before. But i could run them again, when i was using the netbeans64.exe from the installing folder.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me via having set the Working Directory in Netbeans for my project under Project (r. click), Properties, Run, Working Directory; and then subsequently renaming the folder in the computer's filesystem without remembering to change the name in the Working Directory setting as well.
Agreed that having no error message whatsoever from Netbeans is very unhelpful!